# When and Which (PC) Keyboards Introduced Browser and/or Multimedia Keys to Windows

Tags: history, keyboards

**Background:**

Multimedia/Internet keys are additional function keys on PC keyboards that either invoke specific applications like browser, e-mail, media player, etc. or invoked certain function for these applications. They are to be distinguished from ordinary function keys as they are labelled with specific tasks like opening a URL, changing sound volume or alike.

They did show up in great numbers in late 1998 and brought a certain hype, which faded fast in the early 2000s. Here's an especially 'pretty' unit:

[image]

Not only featuring multimedia keys and many labels, but as well made with a case copying the [translucent style made popular by the G3 IMac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G3#Design) ... another hype of the late 1998,

Technical they were simply additional scancodes handled by Windows (or background in general) to start either application/bring it to foreground or be forwarded to the fitting application as messages to invoke functions.

**Question:** Which were the first keyboards to include dedicated keys to invoke an internet browser and/or similar functions.

So far everything I know points to Microsoft (see "Answer" below), but was there anyone going that way before or was it really MS' hardware department that started all of this?

**Please Note:** This question is about keyboards (PS/2, USB) for IBM PC compatible machines and Windows and focuses on browser invocation. I don't mind additional information, but only if they fit the basic idea, so Commodore's Plus4 should not apply.

Comment: It might be helpful to add why this question was considered 'Missing Effort' / 'Being Unclear' or 'Not Useful' by the downvoter. Similar for the closing vote, as it's clearly about historic development of more than 20 years ago. Given, it's about PCs which aren't really cool :)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica You lost me, what development and direction? PC in general? Well, I'd agree a lot, as these keyboards were a joke (for most parts) I was quite laughing about (and still do). None the less, it's one of the many things that have been. I wouldn't have thought about, except a friend asked me yesterday (IRL) and I couldn't give a definite answer (told him a bit about Next and Sun and Apple, but not really when it caught on for the PC and who initiated it.

Comment: I guess it could be considered borderline on topic; but I think not many feel any kind of nostalgia about a random PS/2 or USB keyboard or Wintel machines generally so it's not exactly "retro" as I understand the term. More like "old".

Comment: Nostalgia is not mentioned in the guidelines (https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so I don't think that's a good reason to close this question.  However, this question does pertain to modern hardware still in use (albeit the _history_ of that hardware).  I'll leave the nuances of "on-topic" to others.

Comment: Keyboards and CPUs are still used in modern computers but questions about old keyboards and CPUs are definitely retro. Since this is asking about the *origin* of something that started over twenty years ago I definitely consider this sufficiently retro, even though some keyboard with similar keys are still produced. There's no shortage of reterocomputing YouTube videos on silly tech from this era. I thought they were totally silly even back in the day.

Comment: Multimedia keyboards [had a different meaning at first](https://books.google.fr/books?id=CF2kTIIwVUgC&lpg=PA54&hl=fr&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false) ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Great find. Reminds ma of a similar Siemens Keyboard from the late 90s ... except I do not remember name or date.

Answer (score 9):

#### Not an Answer, but my knowledge so far:

- Microsoft extended the scancodes with the 1994 Microsoft natural Keyboard in 1994 to include Windows and Menue (application) keys.
- With the PC97 guidelines these became a requirement for all (PC97-) standard configurations (See the  p.182 in [Chapter 14 of the PC 97 Hardware Design Guide](http://tech-insider.org/windows/research/acrobat/970711/t_14_io_97.pdf)).
- PC97 included as well a definition for an *Entertainment PC97* which mentions media keys to be added to an (optional) remote (See p.189 of the above document).
- With [Windows 98](http://tech-insider.org/windows/research/acrobat/970711/t_14_io_97.pdf) these scancodes were supported by default.
- During 1998 essentially all manufacturers added 'Multimedia' or 'Internet' Keyboards.

  - Microsoft with the Microsoft Internet Keyboard (they also took it over the edge with their Office Keyboard)
  - IBM had the [Rapid Access Keyboard](https://www-03.ibm.com/press/us/en/pressrelease/2574.wss)
  - Logitech had their [Internet Keyboard](https://docs.rs-online.com/92d9/0900766b8002c7d9.pdf)
  - Compaq's Easy Internet Keyboard even went all the way to include a specific Altavista key and another one to call Yahoos "What's cool".
- I do not know if there was already support in Windows 95, but Logitech states that their keyboard supports the browser keys with Win95

Comment: It might be valuable to learn why this write up was considered _'Not useful'_ by the downvoter.

Comment: I think it is correct to trace this functionality back to the addition of a "meta key" for Windows in 1994. This was something sorely missing for years, and already present for a long time on other systems from the 1980s.

Comment: What do you mean by "meta key"?  The thing with the Windows logo?

Comment: I actually cannot see why the introduction of the "Windows" and "Menu" keys in PC98 would have caused the "Multimedia key" introduction.

Comment: Makes sense. I was pretty sure the Window key appeared separately from the silly multimedia keys but I couldn't remember which came first. Also, it wouldn't surprise me if MS copied the idea from some obscure forgotten keyboard that did it first. Probably wouldn't needed a device driver for extra scancodes before they were standardized but totally doable I would think.

Comment: @another-dave: "meta key" seemed to be a thing on *nix terminals, or possibly X terminals. Used to confuse the hell out of me in the early Linux days. Seems to also be comparable to the Apple key on Macs.

Comment: @tofro Not caused, but preceded - as they were the first keys introduced by Microsoft.

Comment: @hippietrail That's the whole point of the question. Was there someone doing this before Microsoft, if yes, who was it, when and what keyboard.

Comment: @hippietrail - I know the concept of "meta key", but there is no key thus labelled on any PC keyboard I have seen, so I assume the term was used to refer to some other key.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "Altavista key on the Compaq Easy Internet Keyboard" thing? I tried searching and I couldn't find any Compaq keyboards with any search-engine specific keys. The reason I ask is because I have a Compaq keyboard (sdm4540ul) from that era with multimedia keys, and there's a key that looks like a Bullseye, which I'm trying to figure out what could represent.

Comment: @RaleighL. It would be good to post this as a dedicated question (maybe referencing to this) **including a picture** of that keyboard. I suspect you're talking about the one with the long bow on top. In any case, a picture is worth a lot as Compaq made/bought a lot of different 'internet' keyboards. Have you tried to lookup the scan and/or USB codes it delivers? Adding this would be helpful.

Comment: The link to the IBM Rapid Access Keyboard is dead.

Answer (score 7):

On the hardware side of things, I suspect that the first models were the Microsoft Internet Keyboard and the Logitech Internet Keyboard, both launched (as far as I can tell) in 1999. [Andries Brouwer’s list of scancodes](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-6.html) provides a comprehensive list of keyboards implementing multimedia scancodes, but it’s not easy to determine launch dates for all of them...

On the software side of things, the story is quite complex. Support for early multimedia keyboards, and even pre-Windows 95 support for “Windows 95” keyboards (with the Windows and “application” keys), was implemented in add-on device drivers before it became part of device drivers included with the operating system itself.

In Microsoft’s case, this is IntelliType, which supported versions of Windows going back to 3.1 and NT, and is mentioned in [*New Key Support for Microsoft® Windows® Operating Systems and Applications*](http://ftpmirror.your.org/pub/misc/ftp.microsoft.com/peropsys/Win_News/archive/Docs/newkey.zip). Pre-95 support is quite comprehensive: the Windows key brings up the task manager, and with IntelliType 1.1 (released to support 95, but still supporting older versions of Windows), the application key brings up the context menu, if any (by simulating a right-button click!). IntelliType had provisions for OEM licensing (by other keyboard manufacturers), and for multimedia-style shortcuts, but using Windows + number keys:

> Ten Windows logo keys combinations have been reserved for OEM use.  These keys can be used by OEMs to provide keyboard hotkey controls for Speaker Volume, Monitor/LCD Brightness or Contrast, Password or other value added functions.

Logitech and Compaq had similar drivers (Logitech iTouch, and Compaq Easy Access).

Operating system support for client applications in Windows was provided in Windows Me and Windows 2000, with the addition of a number of [virtual key codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) and the [`WM_APPCOMMAND`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-appcommand) window message. This allows various “extra” commands to be handled in applications, and unsurprisingly, ended up determining the keys available on multimedia keyboards: it covers audio equalisation and volume changes, email handling (in detail!), browser navigation, etc. This probably came from remote-control support, and resulted in keyboards in the early 2000s with a large remote-control’s worth of extra keys, regardless of their actual usefulness (who needs extra copy/cut/paste keys on a keyboard?). Thanks to Windows’ message-handling architecture, the messages can be generated by a variety of sources, including (with device driver support) keyboards, remote controls, extra buttons on mice, etc. IntelliType can detect applications which support this message, and will adjust its behaviour accordingly (*e.g.* in “media select” mode).

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying to tie that to Keyboards produced (or rather, branded) by Microsoft themselves, as I would assume the keyboard and OS guys in MS talk to each other:

- The "Microsoft Natural Keyboard" (1994) did introduce the new *Menu*
  and *Windows* keys - It didn't have any multimedia keys.
- The next
  iteration, the "Microsoft Natural Keyboard Elite" (1998) messed up
  the cursor keys and the complete navigational block, but didn't have
  any multimedia keys.
- The "Microsoft Natural Keyboard Pro" (1999) was
  the first to introduce a row of 16 additional blue multimedia and
  power management keys. The fact that it needed specific drivers
  ("Intellitype") to support these keys on Windows before Vista hints
  that these scancodes were not considered in earlier systems.
- The
  "Microsoft Natural Multimedia Keyboard" (2002) got rid of the row of
  nondescript blue buttons for multimedia functions and replaced them
  with a new arrangement of keys that had icons on them.

Comment: The MS departments at least at one point were very separate and very competitive. I've read stories of several silly things that originated in the OS guys wanting things one way and guys doing major apps like Word and Excel or such wanting things another way. So I'm sure it was the same between the software and hardware groups too.

Comment: @hippietrail *In dubio, pro reo*, please

Comment: I had a Microsoft Office keyboard from 2001 which was a behemoth, with a scroll wheel on the left and dedicated cut/copy/paste keys. I loved that keyboard so much ... https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-E17-00002-Office-Keyboard/dp/B00005NVBO